# Jackson serialize get parent

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have Film and Actor classes that are parsed from JSON that looks like this:

```
{
 id: filmId
 cast: [
  {
    id: actorId
    name: 'actorName'
    characters: [
     'character1',
     'character2'
    ]
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

Since actor roles should be mapped by both Film and Actor, I use a custom deserializer on Actor which parses the characters field to `Map<filmId, String>`. But using a custom serializer I am unable to correctly write the JSON for Actor unless I have access to the parent node (to get the filmId).

(1) How do I get access to the parent node during Jackson serialization?
(2) Is there a better object design so that roles are properly mapped by both Actor and Film, perhaps without the need for custom deserialization? The JSON cannot change, however.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Sean, welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep your question sharp and "on point" (like "in sync with the headline"). Consider to separate your question into two, ask about better object design in another question (although it might run the risk as being perceived as "optinion based").